# C++ destroying base class causes debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I'm trying to learn a bit more about polymorphism and I tried to make it as simple as possible, so I got base class Figure and 2 derived classes Rectangle and Circle.

```
class Figure {
public:
    Figure() { cout << "Creating Figure\n"; }
    virtual ~Figure() { cout << "Destroying Figure\n"; }

    virtual double calculateField() {
            return 0;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Figure
{
public:
    Rectangle(double m_a) : p_a(m_a) { cout << "Creating Rectangle\n"; }
    ~Rectangle() { cout << "Destroying Rectangle\n"; }

    virtual double calculateField() {
        return p_a*p_a;
    }

private:
    double p_a; 
};

class Circle : public Figure
{
public:
    Circle(double m_r) : p_r(m_r) { cout << "Creating Circle\n"; }
    ~Circle() { cout << "Destroying Circle\n"; }

    virtual double calculateField() {
        return p_r*3.14*3.14;
    }

private:
    double p_r; 
};
```

In main function I create pointer to Figure class and 2 objects - rectangle and circle. Then I set Figure pointer on 1 of them and call calculateField() on this pointer. It works. But at the end I try to call delete on this pointer and it crashes my program.

```
int main(){
    Figure *ptr = new Figure();
    Rectangle rec(5);
    Circle circ(5);

    cout << "Figure field: " << ptr->calculateField() << endl;

    ptr = &rec; 
    cout << "Rectangle field: " << ptr->calculateField() << endl;

    ptr = &circ;
    cout << "Circle field: " << ptr->calculateField() << endl;

    delete ptr;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Result of this looks like this:

> Creating Figure 
>  Creating Figure 
>  Creating Rectangle 
>   Creating Figure
>  Creating Circle
>  Figure field: 0
>  Rectangle
>   field: 25
>  Circle field: 49.298
>  Destroying Circle
>   Destroying Figure
>
> But then I got Debug Assertion Failed
>
> Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse)

Comment: why are you calling `delete` ? You should only delete something that was created via `new`. Be happy that you can use polymorphism without `new`/`delete` and just dont `delete` anything. Btw you can even avoid pointers and use references instead

Comment: You don't allocate `rec` or `circ` with `new`. Yet you try to (in essence) `delete &circ`. *And* you have a memory leak since you lose the *original* `Figure` object you `new`.

Comment: Off-topic: I would consider making calculateField *pure* virtual within Figure, it does not seem to make much sense trying to give a default implementation for -- unless you have a specific reason for creating "true" figures (in the sense of *not* actually being any sub type...).

Comment: You don't use `new` to create pointers, you use it to create objects. (You also `delete` objects, not pointers.) Do `Figure* ptr = nullptr;` and remove the `delete ptr;`.

Comment: The only objects that can be destroyed using operator `delete` are those created using the corresponding operator `new`.   When `delete ptr` is done in your code, `ptr` points at an object of automatic storage duration (`circ`) which is not created using operator `new`.   Therefore `delete ptr` gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

The program behaviour is undefined.

You can *only* call `delete` on the pointer you get back from `new`.

Currently you're trying to `delete` something that has *automatic storage duration*. That is never going to end well.

Answer (score 3):

You actually create a simple `Figure` at `Figure *ptr = new Figure();`, **but**, you immediately leak it by re-using `ptr` in `ptr = &rec;`

And just before calling `delete` you once again re-used the pointer in `ptr = &circ;`, so in fact you are calling:

```
delete &circ;
```

which is obviously an error.

In fact, everything will be correct provided you never use `ptr` in `new` or `delete` but a different pointer:

```
Figure *ptr, *ptr2 = new Figure();
...
delete ptr2;
```

Comment: When trying to explain the concept, I'd probably shy away from defining multiple pointers in a single statement like that...